# Is the use of the phrase 'There is no woman like me' for this content correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions

If someone wants to say that no one looks as beautiful as her, is it correct to write it like this?

> "There's no woman like me."

For example, if I write a dialog like this, does that reply make sense?

> Person A: "It's a dream come true to meet such beautiful women like
> you."

> Person B: "No, there's no woman like me."

Or should I write instead, "No, there's no other woman like me." ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd opt for the use of either "No, there are no other women like me" or "No, there isn't another woman like me". For the former, using the plural form of "woman", "women", may insinuate the meaning of person B being unique better.

Comment: I think the OP's example has the virtue of brevity, but otherwise there's no particular reason to prefer any of the variations.

Comment: @StuartF
Do those two lines seem disconnected to you? I wonder if I should match the form of the noun 'woman' to make the dialogue flows better, like this: [...such a beautiful woman like you (singular)] and [There is no other woman like me (singular)] or [...such beautiful women like you (plural)] and [There are no other women like me (plural)]. Or is it just fine like that? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Both proposed variations are grammatical and correct. Both mean mostly the same thing, but have slightly different emphasis. Feel free to use whichever you feel is more fitting for your writing style or for the character.